# Gathering list of emails from subdomains

Tags: database, parsing, dom

i'm trying to get every e-mail from this page https://www.atas.com.au/travel-agents?state=vic .
 i'm struggling to find a way for 2 days. Is there anybody that could help me? I will be very grateful, pretty sure that it needs to be done with searching through DOM because they are on subdomains.
I just need to copy them to gmail later. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I added a few more appropriate tags, because you are not yet at the stage where a database is really relevant to your problem.

Comment: Is not clear if you need to write code that can be reused. If not and it's a one time job, I'll advise to search for a "email extractor" tool. Firefox had one https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/email-extractor/ that's not compatible with recent Firefox should work with Firefox < 58.